# Trying to create a program that reads a .txt file, displays it, counts unique words and displays unique words next to how many times used. c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program that reads a .txt file, displays it, counts unique words and displays unique words next to how many times used. So far I have the number of total unique words and the unique words used.  I am a little stuck on how to count the number of times each word was used rather than just the overall total of unique words. How would I display the text from the file as well? My current print statement prints the word the number of times it appears and I want to change it to something like this: " as:  6 " etc...in alphabetical order. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string ask(string msg) {
string ans;
cout << msg;
getline(cin, ans);
return ans;
}

int main() {
ifstream fin( ask("Enter file name: ").c_str()); //open an input stream on 
the given file
if( fin.fail() ) {
    cerr << "An error occurred trying to open the file!\n";
    return 1;
}

istream_iterator<string> it{fin};
set<std::string> uniques;
transform(it, {}, inserter(uniques, uniques.begin()), 
    [](string str) // make it lower case, so case doesn't matter anymore
    {
        transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
        return str; 
    });

cout << "" << endl;
cout << "There are " << uniques.size() << " unique words in the above text." << endl;
cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
cout << " " << endl;    

// display the unique elements
for(auto&& elem: uniques)
    for (int i=0; i < uniques.size(); i++)
        cout << " " << elem << endl;      


// display the size:
cout << std::endl << uniques.size();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: *I am a little stuck on how to count the number of times each word was used* -- Consider using `std::map<std::string, int>` instead of `std::set<std::string>`.

Comment: If I gave you a book and asked you to count how many times each word appears, how would you do it? You are allowed as much paper as you need. Now describe in English the steps to solve the problem. Doing this exercise will help you understand how to write code to solve the problem or fix the code you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count the words, use `map<string, int>`

```
map<string, int> mapObj;
string strObj = "something";
mapObj[strObj] = mapObj[strObj] + 1
```

To display both the word and the counting number

```
for (auto & elem : mapObj) {
    cout << elem.first << ": " << elem.second << endl;
}
```

EDIT: As PaulMcKenzie suggested, `mapObj[strObj]++` is much simpler.

Comment: Using `map` is much simpler:  `mapObj[strObj]++;`

Comment: I got it. Thank you. I need to ask another question seperately

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are right, I just confused myself with `dict` in python, which might raise a KeyError in that situation. Thanks!