# Word Counting Program C++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm currently trying to program a word counting program in C++ and am running into difficulties getting it to parse through a string and separate words from one another. In addition to this I am having a hard time getting the word count for unique words to increment each time the word repeats. My findWord() and DistinctWords() functions are most likely the issues from what I can tell. Perhaps you will see something I do not though in the others, as for the aforementioned functions I have no clue as to what's messing up in them. These are the directions provided by my instructor:

---

Create a program which will count and report on the number of occurrences of distinct, case insensitive words in a text file.

The program should have a loop that:

1.Prompts the user to enter a file name. Terminates the loop and the program if the user presses the Enter key only.

2.Verifies that a file with the name entered exists.  If the file does not exist, display an appropriate message and return to step 1.

3.Reads and displays the contents of the file.

4.Displays a count of the distinct words in the file.

5.Displays a sorted list of each of the distinct words in the file and the number of occurrences of each word. Sort the list in descending order by word count, ascending order by word.

---

I am pretty stuck right now and my assignment is due at midnight. Help would certainly be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time. Here is the code I have, I will also copy paste an example test text file after it:

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>      // Needed to use files
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>    // Needed for sort from standard libraries
using namespace std;

struct WordCount{
    string word;    // Word
    int count;      // Occurence #

    void iCount(){ count++; }

    WordCount(string s){ word = s; count = 1;}
};

// Function prototypes
string InputText();         // Get user file name and get text from said file
string Normalize(string);   // Convert string to lowercase and remove punctuation
vector<WordCount> DistinctWords(string);    // Sorted vector of word count structures
bool findWord(string, vector<WordCount>);   // Linear search for word in vector of structures
void DisplayResults(vector<WordCount>);     // Display results

// Main
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Program Title
    cout << "Lab 9 - Text File Word Counter\n";
    cout << "-------------------------------\n\n";

    // Input text from file
    string buffer = InputText();

    while (buffer != ""){
        // Title for text file reading
        cout << "\nThis is the text string read from the file\n";
        cout << "-------------------------------------------\n";
        cout << buffer << endl << endl;

        // Build vector of words and counts
        vector<WordCount> words = DistinctWords(buffer);

        // Display results
        cout << "There are " << words.size() << " unique words in the above text." << endl;
        cout << "--------------------------------------------" << endl << endl;
        DisplayResults(words);
        buffer = InputText();
    }
    return 0;
}

/***********************************************
InputText() - 
Gets user file name and gets text from the file.
************************************************/
string InputText(){
    string fileName;
    ifstream inputFile;     // Input file stream object
    string str;     // Temporary string
    string text;    // Text file string

    cout << "File name? "; 
    getline(cin, fileName);

    // Case to terminate the program for enter key
    if (fileName.empty()){ exit(0);}

    // Open file
    inputFile.open(fileName);

    if (!inputFile){
        cout << "Error opening data file\n";
        cout << "File name? "; cin >> fileName;
    }
    else{
        while (!inputFile.eof()){
            getline(inputFile, str);
            text += str;
        }
    }
    inputFile.close(); return text;
}

/****************************************************
Normalize(string) - 
Converts string to lowercase and removes punctuation.
*****************************************************/
string Normalize(string s){
    // Initialize variables
    string nString;
    char c;

    // Make all text lowercase
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        c = s[i];
        c = tolower(c);
        nString += c;
    }

    // Remove punctuation
    for (int i = 0; i < nString.length(); i++){
        if (ispunct(nString[i]))
            nString.erase(i, 1);
    }
    // Return converted string
    return nString;
}

/******************************************
vector<WordCount> DistinctWords(string) - 
Sorts vector of word count structures.
*******************************************/
vector<WordCount> DistinctWords(string s){
    vector<WordCount> words; // Initialize vector for words
    string nString = Normalize(s); // Convert passed string to lowercase and remove punctuation

    // Parse string
    istringstream iss(nString);

    while(iss >> nString){
        string n;   // Intialize temporary string

        iss >> n;   // Put word in n
        if (findWord(n, words) == true){ continue; }        // Check to verify that there is no preexisting occurence of the word passed
        else{
            WordCount tempO(n);     // Make structure object with n
            words.push_back(tempO);     // Push structure object into words vector
        }
    }
    return words;
}

/*********************************************
bool findWord(string, vector<WordCount>) -
Linear search for word in vector of structures
**********************************************/
bool findWord(string s, vector<WordCount> words){
    // Search through vector 
    for (auto r : words){
        if (r.word == s){   // Increment count of object if found again
            r.iCount(); return true;
        }
        else        // Go back to main function if not found
            return false;       
    }
}

/***********************************************
void DisplayResults(vector<WordCount>) -
Displays results.
************************************************/
void DisplayResults(vector<WordCount> words){
    // TROUBLESHOOT FIRST ERASE THIS AFTER!!!!!
    cout << "Word"  << setw(20) << "Count\n";
    cout << "-----------------------\n";
    for (auto &r : words){
        cout << setw(6) << left << r.word;
        cout << setw(15) << right << r.count << endl;
    }
}
```

It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity, it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness, it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair, we had everything before us, we had nothing before us, we were all going direct to heaven, we were all going direct the other way - in short, the period was so far like the present period, that some of its noisiest authorities insisted on its being received, for good or for evil, in the superlative degree of comparison only.

[This is the example display he provided for this particular test file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvWuR.jpg)

Comment: I displayed the temporary string attained by parsing through the passed string with istringstream in DistinctWords() prior to the call on findWord() and found that it is skipping over words for some reason. I haven't figured out why yet though. Thought it'd be good for that to be known though.

Comment: [Same assignment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43648054/trying-to-create-a-program-that-reads-a-txt-file-displays-it-counts-unique-wo)

Comment: Check out the warnings from your compiler. It would be better if your question isolated and demonstrated one problem, [mcve]  Running your code, I get 50 unique words, each occuring once.  Is the 50 correct? For a solution, I suggest std::map<std::string, int> where the word is the string index, and the count is the int value.

Comment: This looks very similar to my assignment but mine is using different a vector of structures and istringstream to parse through the string, I'm also very unfamiliar with some of the stuff they're using there. I'm also not sure how they counted their unique words correctly.

Comment: I provided the correct example display of what it is supposed to look like in the hyperlink present at the bottom of the post. There is supposed to be 58 unique words not 50. Also if you look at the 50 that are present with the code I have now some of them are not unique but repeats that somehow got past findWord() and were still pushed back into the vector of structures.

Comment: Where would I apply std::map<std::string, int> ? I tried to look at it a little through other examples of it that I found but I don't understand it.

Comment: does your compiler give warnings on findWord, like "unreachable code" or "not all control paths return a value"?  Or more to the point, both of those. :)

Comment: My compiler gives me zero warnings. It compiles just fine but the results aren't correct. I have this setting for my compiler: -std=c++14 and this for my linker: -static-libgcc. I don't know if that helps at all.

Comment: Well, mine does, but it isn't the actual problem.  Try this:  int main(){vector<WordCount> words = DistinctWords("one one one two"); cout << "There are " << words.size() << " unique words in the above text." << endl; DisplayResults(words);}
I get 2 distinct words (correct) with counts 1, 1 (incorrect).  Now you have something very easy to step through with your debugger, and find the problem. :)

Comment: @Omniok -- The `map` takes the string and pairs it with a count.  Just feed the map a string, and it adds it to the map if it doesn't exist.  Regardless of that, it adds one to the string's "count".  So that map code is just giving the map a string, and bumping up the count.

Comment: When you step through DistinctWords, pay close attention to nString and n.

Comment: Once you figure out that problem, you won't be missing words.  Next up, look at what you do in DistinctWords if you actually find a duplicate. Ask yourself what you should be doing, if you want to keep a count of duplicates.

Comment: Thank you. I'll see where I can get with this and then I'll check back.

Comment: @Omniok Also, all of your operations such as removing punctuation, change casing, etc. are one or two line calls to an STL algorithm function.  There is no need to call `erase` in a loop -- not only is it error prone, it is inefficient the way you're doing things.

Comment: @Omniok To remove punctuation: `nString.erase(std::remove_if(nString.begin(), nString.end(), ::ispunct), nString.end());`  That one line removes all the punctuation from a word. No loops to write, and is much more efficient.  The same with changing to a certain case -- just a call to `transform` using `::tolower`.  Add to that the map, and the only part of the assignment that is tedious is producing the fancy output you're supposed to show.

Comment: Get in the habit of testing your functions separately and not just assuming that they're correct. For instance, try `findWord` when the word is in the vector but is not the first element.

Comment: I've got everything but that crazy tabular output now. Thanks guys! You were all a great help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost had it!
You just forgot to pass the 'words' vector by reference instead of by copy.
Also I included a custom comparator for the sort at the end.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>      // Needed to use files
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>    // Needed for sort from standard libraries
using namespace std;

struct WordCount{
    string word;    // Word
    int count;      // Occurence #

    void iCount(){ count++; }

    WordCount(string s){ word = s; count = 1;}
};

struct {
    bool operator()(const WordCount& a, const WordCount& b)
    {   
        if (a.count < b.count)
            return false;
        else if (a.count > b.count)
            return true;
        else{
            if (a.word < b.word)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }   
} CompareWordCount;

// Function prototypes
string InputText();         // Get user file name and get text from said file
string Normalize(string);   // Convert string to lowercase and remove punctuation
vector<WordCount> DistinctWords(string);    // Sorted vector of word count structures
bool findWord(string, vector<WordCount>&);   // Linear search for word in vector of structures
void DisplayResults(vector<WordCount>);     // Display results

// Main
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Program Title
    cout << "Lab 9 - Text File Word Counter\n";
    cout << "-------------------------------\n\n";

    // Input text from file
    string buffer = InputText();

    while (buffer != ""){
        // Title for text file reading
        cout << "\nThis is the text string read from the file\n";
        cout << "-------------------------------------------\n";
        cout << buffer << endl << endl;

        // Build vector of words and counts
        vector<WordCount> words = DistinctWords(buffer);

        // Display results
        cout << "There are " << words.size() << " unique words in the above text." << endl;
        cout << "--------------------------------------------" << endl << endl;
        DisplayResults(words);
        buffer = InputText();
        buffer = "";
    }
    return 0;
}

/***********************************************
InputText() - 
Gets user file name and gets text from the file.
************************************************/
string InputText(){
    string fileName;
    ifstream inputFile;     // Input file stream object
    string str;     // Temporary string
    string text;    // Text file string

    cout << "File name? "; 
    getline(cin, fileName);
    // Case to terminate the program for enter key
    if (fileName.empty()){ exit(0);}

    // Open file
    inputFile.open(fileName);

    if (!inputFile){
        cout << "Error opening data file\n";
        cout << "File name? "; cin >> fileName;
    }
    else{
        while (!inputFile.eof()){
            getline(inputFile, str);
            text += str;
        }
    }
    inputFile.close(); return text;
}

/****************************************************
Normalize(string) - 
Converts string to lowercase and removes punctuation.
*****************************************************/
string Normalize(string s){
    // Initialize variables
    string nString;
    char c;

    // Make all text lowercase
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        c = s[i];
        c = tolower(c);
        if (isalpha(c) || isblank(c))
            nString += c;
    }

    // Return converted string
    return nString;
}

/******************************************
vector<WordCount> DistinctWords(string) - 
Sorts vector of word count structures.
*******************************************/
vector<WordCount> DistinctWords(string s){
    vector<WordCount> words; // Initialize vector for words
    string nString = Normalize(s); // Convert passed string to lowercase and remove punctuation

    // Parse string
    istringstream iss(nString);

    string n;   // Intialize temporary string
    while(iss >> n){

        if (findWord(n, words) == true){ continue; }        // Check to verify that there is no preexisting occurence of the word passed
        else{
            WordCount tempO(n);     // Make structure object with n
            words.push_back(tempO);     // Push structure object into words vector
        }
    }
    return words;
}

/*********************************************
bool findWord(string, vector<WordCount>) -
Linear search for word in vector of structures
**********************************************/
bool findWord(string s, vector<WordCount>& words){
    // Search through vector 
    for (auto& r : words){
        if (r.word.compare(s) == 0){   // Increment count of object if found again
            r.iCount(); return true;
        }
    }
}

/***********************************************
void DisplayResults(vector<WordCount>) -
Displays results.
************************************************/
void DisplayResults(vector<WordCount> words){
    // TROUBLESHOOT FIRST ERASE THIS AFTER!!!!!
    cout << "Word"  << setw(20) << "Count\n";
    cout << "-----------------------\n";

    sort(words.begin(), words.end(),CompareWordCount);
    for (auto &r : words){
        cout << setw(6) << left << r.word;
        cout << setw(15) << right << r.count << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using map for word count task

```
int main() 
{
  map<string, int> wordCount;

  vector<string> inputWords = {"some", "test", "stuff", "test", 
                                    "stuff"}; //read from file instead

  for(auto& s: inputWords)
      wordCount[s]++;                      //wordCount itself


  for(auto& entry: wordCount)              //print all words and assosiated counts
    cout << entry.first << " " << entry.second <<endl; 


   cout <<wordCount.size() <<endl;      //thats number of distinct words 
}
```